# Angular component test cases getting error : Type Error : Cannot read property "contractno" of undefined

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular-components, web-frontend, angular-test

**While trying to inject default dependency required to run spec file error less getting an error 
like Type Error : Cannot read property "contractno" of undefined**

/** Class userModel**/

```
export class UserModel {
  contractNo: string;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  phoneNo: string;
  emailAddress:string;
}
```

**Here is the component file**
/**contactus component **/

```
    import {
      Component,
      OnInit,
      ViewChild,
      Pipe,
      PipeTransform
    } from "@angular/core;
    import { UserModel } from "../models/User-model.model";
    import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
    import { Router } from "@angular/router";
    import { ContactUsService } from "../service/contact-us.service";
    import { Subscription } from "rxjs";
  export class ContactUsComponent implements OnInit {
      public contactModel: UserModel; 
      constructor(
        private http: HttpClient,
        private router: Router,
        private contactusservice: ContactUsService
      ) {
      }
      ngOnInit() {
        this.loadDefaultUser();
      }
      loadDefaultUser() {
         this.charRemaining = 1000;
         this.contactusmodel = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("data"));       
      }
        }
```

**Here is the component test case file**
  /**contact-us-spec.ts **/

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from "@angular/core/testing";
import { ContactUsComponent } from "./contact-us-component";
import { RouterTestingModule } from "@angular/router/testing";
import { DebugElement, Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { NumberPipePipe } from "./number-pipe.pipe";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from "@angular/common/http/testing";
import { UserModel } from "../models/User-model.model";
import { ContactUsService } from "../service/contact-us.service:;

describe("ContactUsComponent", () => {
  let component: ContactUsComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ContactUsComponent>;
  let debugElement: DebugElement;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ContactUsComponent, NumberPipePipe],
      imports: [RouterTestingModule, FormsModule, HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [ContactUsServices, UserModel ]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(PostLoginContactUsComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it("should create", () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthly();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fixture.detectChanges();` trigger the rendering of the component. I bet in the HTML you use `contactModel.contractno`. Since the `contactModel` is never set, the test fails to render the component because of the described error.

The solution would be either setting the `contactModel` before `fixture.detectChanges();` either adjusting the HTML in such a way, so that is called only if `contactModel` has value.

Comment: tried making object of mock class and tried to set the value of "contratno" but still error is there..and on HTML we are binding model with contactmodel.contractno

Comment: can I see the code sample with those attempts? looking into the currency code I see `UserModel` inside the providers array, which makes no sense. probably there is some other issues in those attempts as well.

Comment: is it possible to provide stackblitz?